# Unexpected default export of anonymous function import/no-anonymous-default-export

Tags: node.js, react-redux

How to avoid this kind of warning? 
It gives warning like below.

```
 Unexpected default export of anonymous function import/no-anonymous-default-exp
```

This is the function which gives warning.

```
import { FETCH_USER } from '../actions/types';

export default function(state = null, action){
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_USER:
            return action.payload || false ;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To avoid this kind of warning, now I am no longer using anonymous functions. So, try this...

```
export default function foo(state = null, action){
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_USER:
            return action.payload || false ;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what happened here? It worked, but I still didn't get exactly how it worked.

Comment: @NetranjitBorgohain An anonymous function is a function without a name. In OP's code, they had export a default function without a name. However, in the above answer, we have given the function the name `foo` instead. By doing this, the function is no longer an anonymous function which prevents the original warning.

Comment: Great description by @khanguslee, but I am surprised to still see this warning in 2024. Anonymous functions play a major role in JavaScript and serverless platforms need you to export them, the name would never be used. This rule should only be used in specific setups where it's not desired

Answer (score 7):

You are getting the error because in this line of code, you have not provided the function name:

```
export default function(state = null, action){
```

The code will still work, however to get rid of the warning provide a function name like so:

```
export default function functionName(state = null, action){
```

Answer (score 2):

What kind of linter are you using? Linters generally don't like default exporting anonymous functions. In eslint, you can disable this on a file by adding this on top of the file:
*`/* eslint-disable import/no-anonymous-default-export */`*

if you want to disable it on a single line, add this comment on top of that line:
*`// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-anonymous-default-export`*

There are no convention with regards to this type of syntax. My tip is to just use put all your exports on the bottom of your file in order to at least have a common structure in your own projects. Just like what the others said, you can get rid of this warning by doing:

```
import { FETCH_USER } from '../actions/types';

const funcName = function(state = null, action){
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_USER:
            return action.payload || false ;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default funcName;
```